# Git: branches without a corresponding file in refs/heads

Tags: git

I have a git repository with lots of branches: `git branch` lists more than 20 branches. But `ls .git/refs/heads` lists only 4 of them. How can that be?

To investigate the issue a bit, I created a test repository in an empty directory, added one file, commited the change and created a new branch `side`. Now `git branch` gives me

```
* master
  side
```

and `ls .git/refs/heads` gives

```
master  side
```

However, after a `git gc`, the files in `.git/refs/heads` disappear, but `git branch` still shows me both branches. Where does git get this information from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your refs are getting packed for performance reasons they can now be found in .git/packed-refs `cat .git/packed-refs`. This man page does a pretty good job of explaining it https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html.